# How to add extra fields in eBay FeedAPI =>getResultFile

Tags: c#, .net-core, ebay-api, ebay-sdk, ebay-net-sdk

We are using eBay FeedAPI => getResultFile to download Inventories. We have successfully downloaded the file by using the TaskId. We need some extra fields along with default fields like Listing Title and UPC. How can we get this information in a file?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/{task_id}/download_result_file
```

We received the following fields:

- SKU
- Price
- CurrencyId
- Quantity
- ItemID

How can we get these additional fields?

- Listing Title
- UPC